# How do i get class name of autoFilled cells in Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using https://datatables.net/

I am trying to get the classnames of the cells that were selected during autoFill and to filter out the inputs based on whether the column is public holiday or not.

How do I achieve that?

Attached below is what i have now.

```
$('#TestTable').DataTable().on( 'autoFill', function ( e, datatable, cells ) {
                            var x = table.cells('.PublicHoliday');
                            alert(cells.length + " " + cells[0].length);
                            alert((cells.length * cells[0].length) + ' cells were updated');
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cells[0][0].cell.node().className
```

The above code solved my problem. For more information, please visit this link: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/54116